# NSWorkspace lauchApplication weirdness - it only works from within Xcode

Tags: objective-c, nsworkspace

```
@implementation button
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)pId;
{

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *currentpath;
    NSString *appPath;

    filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

    appPath=[currentpath stringByAppendingString:@"/resources/systemRun.app"];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:appPath withApplication:nil];

    exit(0);
}
@end
```

This code works perfectly when I build & run from Xcode, or when I right click the "product" from within Xcode. However when I run the application from the finder it never launches ... Even from within the very build folder.. wtf ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `currentDirectoryPath` to find your resources directory.

```
NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle currentBundle] pathForResource:@"systemRun" ofType:@"app"];
```